# Extreme derivatives in Baire class 1

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis

In the 1994 volume of "Differentiation of Real Functions" A. Bruckner poses the following problem (p.41):

"Find necessary and sufficient conditions on a continuous function $F$ that its Dini derivatives be in Baire class 1."

How much progress has been made ever since?